# Printing contents of a vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to get a feel for C++, and I want to either print the contents of a vector, or, to confirm my program is correct, I could add the contents of my vector and print the result.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main(){
  int n;
  vector<int> result;
  cin >> n;
  vector<int> numbers(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    cin >> numbers[i];
  }
  result = numbers;
  cout << result;
  return 0;
}
```

I found some solutions online for printing a vector, but I didn't understand what the code was doing, so I am hoping someone can help.

Comment: What result did you expect and what did you get ?

Comment: Not for SO try CR

Comment: Did you even try searching on your own? There was, already, a question, on SO, with almost the same name.. "_I didn't understand what the code was doing_" So, it's time to grab a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: @JakeFreeman Seeing as this code doesn't compile, it definitely doesn't belong on Code Review. See their [help page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to understand better why this wouldn't fit.

Comment: @scohe001 Ok just a suggestion in case the person got it to compile

Comment: @Jake - I am guessing that CR stands for code review. Link please?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ @JiveDadson

Comment: @JakeFreeman SE Code Review is meant for working code, which that example obviously doesn't fit. Read their question policies before sending someone there please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned "I did not understand what the code is doing", let me briefly describe how to iterate through a container:

The long way:

```
vector<int> result = { 1,2,3 };

for (vector<int>::iterator it = result.begin(); it != result.end() ; it++) {
    int i = *it;
    cout << i << " ";
}
```

Each container provides an iterator, which you can think of a pointer moving forward along the elements of the container. `begin()` returns a pointer to the first element, `end()` returns a pointer to 1 past the last element. Dereferencing the iterator gives the actual value.

For above long way, with [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), C++ provides a shorthand notation with about the same meaning (i.e. it makes use of the iterator-concept but is less "clumsy" in notation):

```
for (auto i : result) {
    cout << i << " ";
}
```

Try it out; hope it helps.

Comment: @Stephen Lechner Thanks for the explanation and the code!

Answer (score 0):

you can print the vector content by making a loop the print every index in the vector size

like

```
for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++){
 cout<<numbers[i];
 }
```

the loop will print every index until the end of the vector

Comment: It's `vector`, not victor.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius thanks

Comment: @Mohamed Mo'nes - Thanks for the reply and the info